# Receiving signed_request using Facebook JS SDK and Meteor

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am trying to build a facebook page tab application using Meteor and have spent an ungodly amount of time just trying to receive a signed_request using just JS. This is incredibly easy using php but I can't use php inside of a Meteor app.

I'm loading the JS SDK within my if (Meteor.isClient) {} Section and it appears to be working. I've tried using FB.Login to get the information I need (Has User Liked Page, Is Admin, ect) but I can't seem to get it working. With page tab applications a user doesn't need to authenticate the app it just runs. The admin is the only that authenticates while installing I think... I can't find anything helpful perusing the Facebook Developer section on creating a facebook page tab application using the JS SDK. Please Help!

Some of my code...

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.fbconnect.connect = function () {
  if (!Session.get("is Facebook JDK loaded?")) {
    Session.set("is Facebook JDK loaded?", true);

    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      // init the FB JS SDK
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'Removed', // App ID, Took away for online question
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

    FB.getAuthResponse(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') { 

                    console.log(response.session.access_token);

                  } else {
                         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                         console.log(response.session.access_token);
                       }
        }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

Comment: Only the `signed_request` that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe contains the page info – and client-side you can’t access POST data, so you will have to do that server-side if you want that info.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the signed_request server side using JS. The FB docs don't have any support for server side JS using something like Node or Meteor...

Comment: It’s just a normal POST parameter, and how to decode it is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/ – yes, the example is for PHP, but it’s quite easy, so translating that into any other language should not be that big of a problem.